# How can I create and touch a document only if none exist for it already?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a case where if there is data in my Firestore database, I want it to fail on create a new document, and definitely not overwrite or send any updates to that document.

I'm doing these in batches so I can't have any batches fail or it kills the whole batch.

Here's what I've tried/ruled out:

`batch.update` - Ruled out due to updating data
`batch.set` - Ruled out as its default is to overwrite the data
`batch.set...{merge: true}` - Ruled out as it would overwrite any fields I already have
`batch.create` - This seemed hopeful but fails when a document already exists

```
let batch = db.batch()
...
batch.xyz(refToCreateOnly, Data) // this should be successful either way such that it does not kill the batch, and only updates if the ref does not exist
...
await batch.commit()
```

Is the best/possibly only way to do this with a transaction?

Comment: Transactions or security rules.

Comment: Do security rules not kill batches if one fails?

Comment: Yes, the entire batch has to succeed, or it's all rolled back.

Comment: If a security rule will kill a batch, and a batch needs to fully succeed, then that won't work. I don't think this is a duplicate. If you don't know to pair your search with security rules you'd never find the first one, and the answers to the second link you posted are about updating only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your only option here is to use a transaction to verify that the document doesn't exist prior to adding it.